# mysql by order by case when cast()

Tags: mysql

I need to sort the ID field, but the id field is dynamic, I need to judge before sorting, if it is a pure number, then I convert it to a numeric type and then sort. But I have some problems in order by case when cast(),can somebody help me?

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for BASIS_EXP_ORG
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `BASIS_EXP_ORG`;
CREATE TABLE `BASIS_EXP_ORG`  (
  `NAME` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'name',
  `ORG_ID` varchar(8) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'org',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ORG_ID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci ROW_FORMAT = Compact;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of BASIS_EXP_ORG
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `BASIS_EXP_ORG` VALUES ('OU_2', '101');
INSERT INTO `BASIS_EXP_ORG` VALUES ('INV_2', '141');
INSERT INTO `BASIS_EXP_ORG` VALUES ('OU_1', '85');

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
select distinct ORG_ID as id,
               NAME    as  text         
          from BASIS_EXP_ORG
         where 1 = 1
         and ORG_ID in (101,141,85)
    order by 
case when ORG_ID  REGEXP '(^[0-9])'
then ORG_ID  +0
ELSE ORG_ID  END
 asc
```

Comment: "I have some problems" - please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and describe the problems you're encountering. Thanks.

Comment: What if it's not a number or a combination of non-numeric with numeric characters? How do you sort them?

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? 
I think you just need to place (ORG_ID + 0) at the order by phase to cast it to numeric type.
Please try this.

```sql
select distinct ORG_ID,
       NAME    as  text         
from BASIS_EXP_ORG
where 1 = 1
   and ORG_ID in (101,141,85)
order by (ORG_ID + 0) DESC
```

Comment: No, because ORG_ID is dynamic, it may be in the form of a string + number, such as c001, or it may be a pure number, such as 101, so I need to judge it before sorting.

Comment: yes dik11, I just tested and the above query seems work for your both cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL version 8+ and MariaDB 10+, you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to remove strings then `CAST` it:

```
 SELECT   DISTINCT ORG_ID AS id,CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(ORG_ID,'[a-zA-Z]','') AS SIGNED),
          NAME AS  TEXT         
 FROM     BASIS_EXP_ORG
 WHERE    1 = 1
 ORDER BY CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(ORG_ID,'[a-zA-Z]','') AS SIGNED) ASC;
```

Check demo here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/itK8PM7WjURn5Jaynurz4N/0

I added a few row data in the fiddle and remove the `and ORG_ID in (101,141,85)` in `WHERE` condition for testing purpose.

**EDIT:**
This query below should be able to get it working on older MySQL:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ORG_ID AS id,SUBSTRING(ORG_ID,
        LEAST(
        IF(LOCATE(1,org_id)=0,99,LOCATE(1,org_id)),
        IF(LOCATE(2,org_id)=0,99,LOCATE(2,org_id)),
        IF(LOCATE(3,org_id)=0,99,LOCATE(3,org_id)),
        IF(LOCATE(4,org_id)=0,99,LOCATE(4,org_id)),
        IF(LOCATE(5,org_id)=0,99,LOCATE(5,org_id)),
        IF(LOCATE(6,org_id)=0,99,LOCATE(6,org_id)),
        IF(LOCATE(7,org_id)=0,99,LOCATE(7,org_id)),
        IF(LOCATE(8,org_id)=0,99,LOCATE(8,org_id)),
        IF(LOCATE(9,org_id)=0,99,LOCATE(9,org_id))),99)+0 AS num,
          NAME AS TEXT         
 FROM     BASIS_EXP_ORG
 WHERE    1  = 1
 ORDER BY num ASC;
```

Demo on MySQL 5.7: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/itK8PM7WjURn5Jaynurz4N/3

As you can see, I'm using a series of functions to remove the strings from the original data. First I use `LOCATE` to find numbers range from 1-9 and their location. The following query and result can help to clarify more:

```
 SELECT *,
        LOCATE(1,org_id),
        LOCATE(2,org_id),
        LOCATE(3,org_id),
        LOCATE(4,org_id),
        LOCATE(5,org_id),
        LOCATE(6,org_id),
        LOCATE(7,org_id),
        LOCATE(8,org_id),
        LOCATE(9,org_id) FROM BASIS_EXP_ORG;

+-------+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| NAME  |  ORG_ID  |   LOCATE   |   LOCATE   |   LOCATE   |   LOCATE   |   LOCATE   |   LOCATE   |   LOCATE   |   LOCATE   |   LOCATE   |
|       |          | (1,org_id) | (2,org_id) | (3,org_id) | (4,org_id) | (5,org_id) | (6,org_id) | (7,org_id) | (8,org_id) | (9,org_id) |
+-------+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| OU_1  | 00000001 | 8          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          |
| OU_2  | 101      | 1          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          |
| INV_2 | 141      | 1          | 0          | 0          | 2          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          |
| OU_3  | 81       | 2          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 1          | 0          |
| OU_1  | 85       | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 2          | 0          | 0          | 1          | 0          |
| INV_2 | a101     | 2          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          |
| OU_1  | b40      | 0          | 0          | 0          | 2          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          |
| OU_1  | c0001    | 5          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          |
| OU_2  | c101     | 2          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          |
+-------+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

The logic behind this is to know where is the location of the number stated in `LOCATE` (if any). Then if it returns `0` (meaning the number doesn't exists), give it `99` so when the `LEAST` happen, it won't see zeros. The main reason of using `LEAST` however is to get the first number found instead of the smallest number found. That being said, refer to the example above and look for the data with `ORG_ID=81`. `(LOCATE(1,org_id)` found number 1 in location 2 while `(LOCATE(8,org_id)` found the number 8 in location 1. If we took the smallest number to judge, then we will get number 1 instead of 81 in the `SUBSTRING` function (this took me a while to figure out ;P). Then we use them all in the `SUBSTRING` and we add `+0` at the last value retrieved.

tl;dr > if we convert this into plain query, we will get basically something like this:

```
SELECT   DISTINCT ORG_ID AS id, SUBSTRING(ORG_ID,**8**,99)+0 as num
FROM     BASIS_EXP_ORG
WHERE    1  = 1
AND      ORG_ID='00000001'
ORDER BY num ASC;
```

To obtain the `**8**` is where all the process happen.

Comment: oh bummer.. it's going to be tricky to achieve this.. I'll try something

Comment: @dik11 , please check my updated answer if it can apply to your situation. Thanks